# How to name the output frames based on their presentation timestamp?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to extract frames from videos. Using the generic command

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi out%d.png
```

I am getting all the frames but I want the names of the frames to indicate their presentation timestamp in the video, i.e. the hour, minute, second and millisecond.

For example if a frame is shown in the movie at time 0 hours 5 minutes 30 seconds and 37 milliseconds, then the output frame should be named: `out_00_05_30_37.png`.

Any help?

Comment: Very relevant related ticket: [`%t` syntax support for image2 muxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1452).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out any easy way in which I can play with `ffmpeg` arguments and solve my problem. So I figured another workaround as also suggested by user:dstob.
Let's say I need to store 10 frames per second, then I can iterate the time by 0.1 second and using the `-ss` argument I can seek the movie to that particular timestamp. Now I will know which frame to extract and the timestamp of that frame too. Following is my code, though it is in MATLAB the overall idea is to iterate over time.

```
%your movie name
movie = 'movie_name.mp4';

%get the duration of movie in seconds
[to,te] = system(['ffprobe -i ' movie ' -show_format -v quiet | grep duration']);
tmp_ = strsplit(te,'=');
total_time = floor(str2num(tmp_{2}));

%initialize the timer in milliseconds
curr_time = 0;

while curr_time < total_time*1000
    %iterate 10 times in 1 second to get 10 frames
    for i=1:10
            time_ = curr_time + 100*i;                       
            milli_sec = floor(mod(time_,1000));         %milliseconds
            time_ = floor(time_ / 1000);               
            sec = floor(mod(time_,60));                 %seconds;
            time_ = floor(time_ / 60);                 
            min = floor(mod(time_,60));                 %minutes;
            hour = floor(time_ / 60);                   %hour
            frame_name = sprintf('out_%.2d_%.2d_%.2d_%.3d.png',hour,min,sec,milli_sec);

            %Set the ffmpeg command to seek it to the time you want and
            %store the frame
            cmnd = sprintf('ffmpeg -ss %.2d:%.2d:%.2d.%.3d -i %s -frames:v 1 %s',hour,min,sec,milli_sec,movie,frame_name);
            system(cmnd);                               
    end;
    curr_time = curr_time + 1000;         %increment the timer by 1 second
end;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This might be inaccurate if the frame rate is not estimated correctly (which may happen quite often). What you could do is `ffprobe input.mp4 -select_streams v -of compact -show_frames -show_entries frame=best_effort_timestamp_time` – and based on *these* timestamps rename each output file. The rest is just a programming exercise :)

Comment: What exactly can be inaccurate? The duration of movie using `fprobe` or using `ffmpeg -ss` argument?

Comment: Well, let's say you don't care what the framerate of the original video is, but you just want to output 10 frames per second of input video by using `ffmpeg -ss 0.1 ...`, `ffmpeg -ss 0.2` etc. In a "real" video, the presentation timestamps of the frames are most probably not at exactly these timestamps, so you may get the same frames output twice. For example, for a 24fps video, the frames are at `0.0`, `0.04167`, `0.0833`, `0.125` etc., so you really want `ffmpeg -ss 0.125` in that case. But if you don't care about frame accuracy, then it doesn't matter so much.

Comment: The frame rates are usually 20+fps and if I am extracting 10 frames per second, then I think the occurrence of redundancy is a bit difficult. Yes, I don't have to worry much about the frame accuracy so this will work fine for me. Thanks for the information :)

Answer (score 0):

If frame-rate is constant then you could just create a script to rename the files. I do not know of a way to do it within ffmpeg.

If you wanted to automate things a bit more you could use ffprobe to generate your frame information and use that time-stamp information to rename the files.